# Eclipse refactoring tutorials

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know of a website that has a tutorial and example of each Refactoring technique used in Eclipse?  I can't find one.

Comment: Edited: "refractoring" becomes "refactoring"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-refactoring/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw97Refractoringdth-OS&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grlnxw97

http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?fromSeriesID=6&name=IntroductionToEclipseWithJava3_JohnM

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19062.html